# Django not showing a model in admin page

Tags: python, django

I have created a new model for my app `Consumptions` but it doesn't show up.
I know that I have to put it on the admin.py page but still not working.
I don't know what could be happening

This is my **models.py** page:

```
from logs.mixins import LogsMixin

# Other models

class MF(LogsMixin, models.Model):
    """Definición del modelo de Proveedor."""

    name = models.CharField("Nombre", null=False, default="MF", max_length=50)

    class Meta:

        verbose_name = 'Módulo formativo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Módulos formativos'

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name

 # Other models
```

And this is my **admin.py** page:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Provider, Consumption, Message, Course, Call, Platform, MF

admin.site.register(Provider)
admin.site.register(Consumption)
admin.site.register(Message)
admin.site.register(Course)
admin.site.register(Call)
admin.site.register(Platform)
admin.site.register(MF)
```

As you can see is not my only model, I do the same with all of them but the **MF** one is not showing up on the admin page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us your directory tree?

Comment: It can't be about the path, the other models are working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try following approach:

```
class ProviderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Provider

admin.site.register(Provider, ProviderAdmin)
```

In `ProviderAdmin` class you may specify filters, search fields or empty value handling:

```
search_fields = ('',)
list_filter = ('',)
empty_value_display = 'empty'
```

Comment: Then you should specify what actually happens. Does it return any error? Did you register your app?

Comment: My app is registered. The other models show up correctly but not "MF". It doesn't return any errors, it just doesnt show then MF model.